# Can anybody explain to me what collection instance is?

Tags: operator, collections

I have tried understanding this operator, but I cannot seem to wrap my mind around it.

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/properties/instancing/collection.html

Answer (score 1):

A collection instance is simply a *linked* copy of another collection. If you change the original collection, all instances will also update to reflect your change. Here's a simple video that demonstrates how it works:

https://youtu.be/Id9IzLV7IDg